# Как развернуть перебор последовательности в списке Python?

Tags: python, list, sympy

Перебираю список, который в ходе применения к нему функции `prod()` модуля `sympy` почему-то переворачивается, давая результат с конца.

Получаю так:

> (−2.5133)(−2.1991)...(−0.3142)

А надо наоборот:

> (−0.3142)(−0.6283)...(−2.5133)

Код:

```
from sympy import symbols, prod

x = symbols('x')
x_col_list=[0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283, 0.9425, 1.2566, 1.5708, 1.885, 2.1991, 2.5133]
prod([x - args for args in x_col_list])
```

Кроме того, `x` с нулем сразу усекается до x, а мне надо `(x - 0)`

Comment: Попробуйте  for args in x_col_list[::-1]

Comment: @Bol4onok, сделав `prod([x - args for args in x_col_list[::-1]])` получил тот же результат

Comment: А попробуйте применить [::-1] на итоговый list, то есть вот так: [x - args for args in x_col_list][::-1]

Comment: @Bol4onok, так же выходит: вспять не обращается

Comment: @Bol4onok, moreover, I decided to try this way: turn the list `x_col_list`, and then iterate over it. But the result is the same - nothing has changed after the `prod()` function

Comment: Скорее всего prod сам сортирует итерируемый объект, иначе я не понимаю почему это так работает.

Comment: Система компьютерной алгебры сама решает как упорядочить множители. Почему это доставляет вам неудобства? С точки зрения математики разницы никакой.